# SQL Using join but without on Condition

Tags: sql

I am looking for someone to help by updating this sql statement, as I want to join two tables but without using " ON AD.[UID] = UI.[UID]  " ?

```
SELECT AD.[AdsID] ,AD.[UID] ,AD.[Section] ,AD.[Category] ,AD.[Country] ,AD.[State] ,AD.[City] ,SUBSTRING([AdsTit],1,30)+'...' as AdsTit ,SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,85) as AdsDesc ,AD.[AdsPrice] ,AD.[Img1] ,AD.[Currency] ,AD.[Section] ,AD.[Currency] ,AD.[AdsDate] ,AD.[approvAds] ,UI.[approv] 
FROM [ads] as AD JOIN UserInfo as UI ON AD.[UID] = UI.[UID] 
where AD.[Country] = @Location AND AD.[approvAds]= 'Y' AND UI.[approv]='Y'  
ORDER BY [AdsDate] DESC
```

Comment: do you have any FKs?

Comment: what DB engine you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move condition from 'on' to 'where', it works like inner join

```
SELECT AD.[AdsID] ,AD.[UID] ,AD.[Section] ,AD.[Category] ,AD.[Country] ,AD.[State] ,AD.[City] ,SUBSTRING([AdsTit],1,30)+'...' as AdsTit ,SUBSTRING([AdsDesc],1,85) as AdsDesc ,AD.[AdsPrice] ,AD.[Img1] ,AD.[Currency] ,AD.[Section] ,AD.[Currency] ,AD.[AdsDate] ,AD.[approvAds] ,UI.[approv] 
FROM [ads] as AD, UserInfo as UI
where AD.[UID] = UI.[UID] 
and AD.[Country] = @Location AND AD.[approvAds]= 'Y' AND UI.[approv]='Y'  
ORDER BY [AdsDate] DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`USING`](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqljusing.html) keyword instead of `ON` in your SQL query or use a [natural join](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/natural-join.php), which compares all the common columns in two tables itself without the on condition.

Query for your tables like this:

```
select AD.column1, AD.column2, UI.column1, UI.column2........  
from ads AD join userinfo UI using(UID)  
where AD.country='location' and AD.ApprovAds='y' and UI.approv='y'  
order by Ads(date) desc
```

Or

```
select AD.column1, AD.column2, UI.column1, UI.column2........  
from ads  AD natural join userinfo UI  
where AD.country='location' and AD.ApprovAds='y' and UI.approv='y'  
order by Ads(date) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

you want a **cross join**, don't recommend doing this as the performance is better on a join with a conditional statement.

That being said here is how you do it:

```
SELECT A.*, B.* 
FROM A CROSS JOIN B
WHERE A.Id = B.AId
```

Just put the tables you need in place of A and B statements